# Entity Framework 6: Custom navigation without foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

we are wondering, how it is possible with EF to define a custom navigation without a foreign key being necessary/ generated. Study case:

1. There shall be two objects, Funds and Prices.
   2.1 A Fund can have many prices.
   2.2 Prices are historic, the latest price is flagged.
2. The link between fund and prices is on the IsinCode, not the primary keys.
3. IsinCode and IsLatest are having a unique constraint (there can be only 1 price per isin being latest)

The sql would look like the following:

```
select * from Funds f 
 join Prices p on f.IsinCode = p.IsinCode and p.IsLatest=1
```

The closest we are able to setup in the EF model builder looks like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Fund>(e =>
{
  e.HasOne(ex => ex.LatestPrice)
    WithMany()
    HasPrincipalKey(pk => pk.IsinCode) // not considering constraint IsLatest =1
}
```

--> this attempt brings the issue that EF wants either a unique key on `IsinCode` or a unique constraing (both fail)

A many-to-many relation brings the issue that we load way too much data to drop all but latest. Any idea how such a navigation can be expressed with EF?

Comment: If this is not EF core you must declare Prices.IsInCode as the Key in EF.  It doesn't have to be the PK in the database.  A Unique constraint is fine.

Comment: We cannot declare a unique constaint only on this field because prices for the same IsinCode can coexist with other dates. We can/ have following unique constraints:
1. IsinCode & IsLatest when IsLatest=1
2. IsinCode & date